# Modifying text with SPAN tags without messing up the formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I have a text input area on my page where I can paste text, and then a function that separates the individual words and adds styling to them based on the word.

My goal is to have each individual word clickable (to activate a function while passing in that word as a parameter) and to add the word as a class to its span tag wrapper.

But the problems I keep running into are that the function removes any formatting from the text, like linebreaks, and that it can't separate out punctuation around words. Like " dog. ", "dog" and "'dog'" all being treated as separate classes because of the punctuation surrounding them.

```
const textArea = document.getElementById("text-area") //text input
const renderedText = document.getElementById("rendered-text") //div to add text to
let word
let wordClass

function enterText() {
  renderedText.textContent = textArea.value
  let words = renderedText.outerText.split(" ")
  while (renderedText.hasChildNodes()) {
    renderedText.removeChild(renderedText.firstChild)
  }
  words.map((el) => {
      word = document.createElement("span")
      wordClass = el.toLowerCase()
      word.innerText = el
      word.classList.add(wordClass)
      word.setAttribute("onclick", `testFunc("${wordClass}")`)
      renderedText.appendChild(word)
      renderedText.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", " ")
  })
}
```

This function has at least allowed me to dynamically add classes based on the particular word, and to make each word clickable. But it doesn't seem like the right approach since I want to keep formatting the same and ignore certain punctuation surrounding words.

Comment: you could clear your text from any punctuation character before splitting it.

Comment: @GrafiCode how can I do that? And also, how do I place it back together afterward? 
Like if I want to separate "word." from the . and make it <span class='word' onclick='Function("word")'>word<span>. and still place the period after, how would I do that? I can't figure it out.

Comment: ah sorry, I thought you didn't want to keep any character except words. I mean, I guess something like `didn't` you want to keep it intact too

Comment: @GrafiCode Yeah I would like to keep words like "didn't" and "don't". So I am even willing to just let single quotes be an exception and not filter those at all. But periods, commas, double quotes, etc... I don't want to include them within the span tags.